# What happens when I add duplicate element into HashSet? Is old element overwritten or not?

Tags: java, duplicates, addition, hashset

Say I want to add duplicate element in `HashSet`. We know that is not allowed. So I came across 2, let's say *theories*.

Under 'PROPERTIES, number 2' of this [link](https://javaconceptoftheday.com/java-collection-framework-hashset-class/), it says:

> HashSet does not allow duplicate elements. If you try to insert a
> duplicate element, older element will be overwritten

But when I check docs that are provided to me in IDE, in method `add()`, it states:

> ```
> * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
> * unchanged and returns {@code false}.
> ```

So does it overwrite(replace) old element or it leaves the set unchanged and returns false? :) Am I crazy of they say exactly the opposite?

Comment: The IDE takes that from the official documentation. The other is just some random site. Who would you rather believe?

Comment: The IDE :) But how could people that made that site make such a big mistake then?

Comment: You can't be *that* new to the internet :-)

Comment: @Stefan because for all intents and purposes the outcome is the same :) Also, what tevemadar said :P

Comment: @tevemadar Hahah true.. But the problem is those "random" sites sometimes make 'prettier' explanation of some concepts. Official docs are sometimes too hard to follow for me as a beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE is displaying an excerpt from the official specification (the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-)) for the `Set.add` method.

The IDE is correct.  Trust the official documentation, not some "pretty" website.

---

> But how could people that made that site make such a big mistake then?

Always remember that the primary motivation for websites like the one you found is to earn money from your page views.  They often pay more attention to "search engine optimization" than they do the quality of their material.

---

> But the problem is those "random" sites sometimes make 'prettier' explanation of some concepts. Official docs are sometimes too hard to follow for me as a beginner.

So which is preferable?  Something that easy to read, but wrong?  Or something that is accurate?

In this case, you cannot argue that the official document is hard to understand.  You yourself were able to see that the contradiction between the text taken from the official documentation and the 3rd-party website.

My advice us to always try to read the Official javadocs first, and always believe it ahead of any other sources ... *including StackOverflow answers!!*  The only thing that is more definitive<sup>1</sup> is the OpenJDK source code.

---

<sup>1 - And even that is debatable.  On the one hand, the code determines what actually happens.  On the other hand, the code may change from one version to another.  So relying on behavior that is not *specified* in the javadocs may result in portability issues.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Any the theories can be verified by looking at the source code.

For example, for JDK 8, [`HashSet::add`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) implemented as follows:

```java
/**
     * Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
     * More formally, adds the specified element <tt>e</tt> to this set if
     * this set contains no element <tt>e2</tt> such that
     * <tt>(e==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e2==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;e.equals(e2))</tt>.
     * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
     * unchanged and returns <tt>false</tt>.
     *
     * @param e element to be added to this set
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
     * element
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

Here `map` is an instance of `HashMap`, so we should look at [`HashMap::put`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java):

```java
 /**
     * Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map.
     * If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old
     * value is replaced.
     *
     * @param key key with which the specified value is to be associated
     * @param value value to be associated with the specified key
     * @return the previous value associated with <tt>key</tt>, or
     *         <tt>null</tt> if there was no mapping for <tt>key</tt>.
     *         (A <tt>null</tt> return can also indicate that the map
     *         previously associated <tt>null</tt> with <tt>key</tt>.)
     */
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
    }
```

and implementation of `putVal` contains this code:

```java
            if (e != null) { // existing mapping for key
                V oldValue = e.value;
                if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                    e.value = value;
                afterNodeAccess(e);
                return oldValue;
            }
```

Comment: It is much better to consult the official javadoc than to look at the source code.  The source code can change (and has changed) from one version of Java to the next, but the javadoc is more than documentation, it is a *contract* which specifies guaranteed behavior, forever, regardless of the internal implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the program below and you'll see the duplicate elements are not allowed:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Test {
    public static class Dummy{
         String s1;
         String s2;
        public Dummy(String s1, String s2) {
            super();
            this.s1 = s1;
            this.s2 = s2;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((s1 == null) ? 0 : s1.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Dummy other = (Dummy) obj;
            if (s1 == null) {
                if (other.s1 != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!s1.equals(other.s1))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Dummy [s1=" + s1 + ", s2=" + s2 + "]";
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Object>hashSet =new HashSet<>();
        Object o1 = new Dummy("a","b");
        Object o2 = new Dummy("a","c");
        System.out.println(o1.equals(o2));
        hashSet.add(o1);
        System.out.println(hashSet);
        hashSet.add(o2);
        System.out.println(hashSet);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The IDE says "unchanged", which includes two cases.

1. Overwrite the old element, so keep "unchanged".
2. Do not modify, so keep "unchanged".

To determine which case is correct, we need to look for the answer in the source code of the `add` method in `HashSet`.

First, the `add` method calls the `put` method in `HashMap`:

```java
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Then, the `put` method calls the `putVal` method:

```java
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
               boolean evict) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
    if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
        n = (tab = resize()).length;
    if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null)
        tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
    else {
        Node<K,V> e; K k;
        if (p.hash == hash &&
            ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            e = p;
        else if (p instanceof TreeNode)
            e = ((TreeNode<K,V>)p).putTreeVal(this, tab, hash, key, value);
        else {
            for (int binCount = 0; ; ++binCount) {
                if ((e = p.next) == null) {
                    p.next = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
                    if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD - 1)
                        treeifyBin(tab, hash);
                    break;
                }
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    break;
                p = e;
            }
        }
        if (e != null) { 
            V oldValue = e.value;
            if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
                e.value = value;
            return oldValue;
        }
    }
    ++modCount;
    if (++size > threshold)
        resize();
    return null;
}
```

The key part is:

```java
if (e != null) { 
    V oldValue = e.value;
    if (!onlyIfAbsent || oldValue == null)
        e.value = value;
    return oldValue;
}
```

Firstly, the code will check whether the found matching node `e` is null. If it is not `null`, it means that there is already a node in the hash table whose key is the same as the key of the newly inserted node, and the value of this node needs to be updated.

Then, the code stores the old value of the same node in the `oldValue` variable.

**Next, the code checks whether it needs to update the value of the node. If `onlyIfAbsent` is false or the old value is null, it means that the value of the node needs to be updated.** Since the `put` method passes the `onlyIfAbsent` parameter as false, it is here that a new value overwrites the old value, which proves that the first case is correct (overwrite the old element, so keep "unchanged").